# Recovering SVN repository

Tags: svn

I maintain an SVN repository on an external hard disk, and it appears to have gotten corrupted in some manner. (A second repository on the same disk is fine).

Running `svnadmin verify` gives the message:

```
svnadmin: No such revision 0
```

Attempting a recovery results in:

```
Repository lock acquired.
Please wait; recovering the repository may take some time...
svnadmin: Revision 139 has a revs file but no revprops file
```

I've sought for help based on the 'no revprops' message, but encountered only code and test references that produce it. No info on how to recover from it.

This first appeared when attempting a commit. It had been some time since I've worked with this code base, so this is the first commit in several months. The check-in attempt produced:

```
Transmitting file data ..svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Can't move '/media/jj1/repositories/xxxxxx/db/transactions/138-3z.txn/props' to '/media/jj1/repositories/xxxxxx/db/revprops/0/139': Input/output error
```

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but you could try looking for outstanding transactions: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.diskspace.deadtxns

Comment: lstxns shows no outstanding transactions.

Comment: does the disk or filesystem have have errors? Are ownership or permissions different?

Comment: Nope, the disk has been essentially dormant for several months, plugged in via USB, but otherwise unused.